# Thread status in an async request

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, future

I would like to know what happen with the thread in spring when I make an @async call and I retrieve the value in a Future type field. Is the thread idle meanwhile?.

Thanks in advance,
Gonza.

Answer (score 0):

The thread starts immediately after your call to the `@Async` method. You can use the `Future` instance to check the current status - `isDone()`. Or you can call `get()` which will block until the thread completes.